# Find the Taylor series for $f(z)=\frac{i}{(z-i)(z-2i)}$ about $z_0=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series for $f(z)=\frac{i}{(z-i)(z-2i)}$ about $z_0=0$ and the disk of convergence.

For the Taylor series I got
$-\frac{i}{2}+\frac{z(2+i)}{4}-\frac{z(2i+3)}{2!}...$, but I'm not super confident in it. Can someone confirm or deny if it's correct?

To find this I simply used the $(_0)+\frac{′(_0)}{1!}(−0)+\frac{″(_0)}{2!}(−_0)^2+⋯$ expansion. I double checked with a derivative calculator so I know my values are right, I just wanted to double check that this is the right way to do it. I always thought it was, but that's not how my complex analysis class does it and I don't understand their way.

Comment: I don't know how you found your Taylor series, but an easy way would be finding the partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)$.

Comment: Regarding the disc of convergence: A helpful fact to keep in mind would be that the power series centred at $z_0$ is valid on the maximal (open) disc contained in the domain of the function. This shows you that the power series converges on $\{|z| < 1\}$. (Why?) Moreover, using continuity, you can also show that it cannot converge on any larger disc. (How?)

Comment: As for verifying the Taylor series, it would more helpful if you could [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3752441/edit) your question and show us how you derived it. (So even if you made a calculation error, you would know whether your method is correct. Moreover, someone could point out an alternative method.)

Comment: I edited to add how I found my Taylor series! My bad for not having it the first time.

Comment: As for the disc of convergence I know that $|z|<1$, but I have difficulty going from there. The previous ones I have done had a generic mother function Taylor series that I could rewrite my expression in the form of, then I would set in my newly written expression I would find my new "$z$" and then substitute it in to $|z|<1$, then simplify. I don't know if I can do that here or how to.

Comment: Great, so the method of finding the Taylor series is indeed correct. (However, the method pointed out by @Batominovski is much simpler.) Also, you've mentioned another way of doing it as shown in your class; maybe you could write that as well to get clarifications. (Perhaps as a separate question because I think it is usually preferred to have only one question per post.)

Comment: "As for the disc of convergence I know that $|z|<1$, but I have difficulty going from there." I didn't really understand. Do you "know" in the sense that you know that that's the answer but don't know how to derive it? Because otherwise, I don't see what you mean by "going from there" since that's all that you wanted to show.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask it as a new question thanks!

Comment: I know in the sense that it is part of the answer, but I don't truly understand it. My homework has questions about it, but my class went over that very briefly without any examples. Everything I've learned about it has been either on this forum or by googling questions about it. So all I'm trying to show is $|z|<1$? I had a previous question with $\frac{3}{1+z}$ where I found it could be rewritten as $\frac{3}{1-\frac{-(z-1)}{2}}$, modeled after $\frac{1}{1-z}$ where $z$ would be $\frac{-(z-1)}{2}$ so I substituted in $|\frac{-(z-1)}{2}|<1$ to get $|z-1|<2$ for the disc.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you know the fact that I mentioned in my first comment? (Second comment overall in this thread.)

Comment: Yes! What I understood from that is (please correct me if I'm wrong) that a power series cannot converge all over the complex plane. In fact, it can only converge on a disc represented by $|z|<1$. Now what I'm slightly confused on... How does $z_0$ relate to $|z|<1$ here?

Comment: What you have said is not correct if you're talking about power series in general. There are many power series that converge on all of $\Bbb C$. For example, $\sum 0z^n$ or a less-trivial example: $\sum \dfrac{z^n}{n!}$. I have added an answer explaining why $|z| < 1$ is the series of convergence for this particular series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{i,2i\}$,\begin{align}\frac i{(z-i)(z-2i)}&=\frac1{i-z}-\frac1{2i-z}\\&=-\frac i{1+iz}+\frac12\frac i{1+iz/2}.\end{align}Therefore, if $|z|<1$,\begin{align}\frac i{(z-i)(z-2i)}&=-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-iz)^n+\frac i2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{iz}2\right)^n\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left((-i)^{n+1}-\left(-\frac i2\right)^{n+1}\right)z^n\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-i)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right)z^n.\end{align}So, this last power series is the Taylor series that you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Answer regarding the disc of convergence:

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $f:\Omega \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic and let $z_0 \in \Omega$. Then, $f$ admits a power series representation centred at $z_0$. Moreover, this power series agrees with $f$ on the maximal open disc $D \subset \Omega$ centred at $z_0$.

---

In this case, we have $\Omega = \Bbb C\setminus \{i, 2i\}$ and $z_0 = 0$.
Thus, the $D$ as in the theorem will be $D = \{z : |z| < 1\}$.
(Verify that $D$ is indeed contained $\Omega$ and that any larger disc would contain $i$.)

Thus, the power series (centred at $z_0 = 0$) $\sum a_nz^n$ that you derived will be equal to $f$ on $D$.

Now, here is the claim that we want to make:

**Claim.** $D$ is the disc of convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$.
Note that the above claim says precisely two things:

1. $\sum a_nz^n$ converges for every $z \in D$.
2. If we take any larger disc $D' \supsetneq D$, then there exists $z \in D'$ such that $\sum a_nz^n$ diverges.

*Proof.* The proof of 1. follows from the Theorem.
Let us focus on 2.

Let $D'$ be any (strictly) larger disc and let us assume that the power series converges on it.
Then, the function $$g(z) = \sum a_nz^n$$ is well-defined on $D'$. Moreover, it is continuous on $D'$. (A standard fact about power series.)

Also, we know that $f$ and $g$ agree on $D$. Moreover, $i \in D'$.
(In particular, $g(i)$ is defined and is a (finite) complex number.)

Now, let us take any sequence $(z_n)$ in $D$ such that $z_n \to i$. Since $f$ and $g$ agree on $D$, we get that $$f(z_n) = g(z_n)$$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. However, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we see that $$|f(z_n)| \to \infty; \quad |g(z_n)| \to |g(i)| < \infty,$$
a contradiction! (The fact that $|f(z_n)| \to \infty$ follows from the function definition of $f$.)